# Argumentos en C y como trabajar con ellos

Tags: c, parametros

Me surgen algunas dudas sobre los argumentos en C:

Supongamos que tengo una función `main` en a la que le quiero pasar 3 parámetros cuando llame a mi programa, en primer lugar un nombre "Pepe", en segundo lugar un `int`, que sería su edad y en tercer lugar un `float`, que puede ser dinero en cartera.

```
main (int argc, char *argv[]) {
    int edad;
    char nombre[30];
    floar dinero;

       strcpy(nombre, argv[1])
        edad = argv[2];
        dinero = argv[3];
   
    edad = edad + 5;
    dinero = dinero + 3;
    
    printf("Mi nombre es %s, mi edad es %d y tengo %f dinero en la cartera, nombre, edad, dinero);
    
}
```

Ahora llamo a mi programa y trato de compilarlo con los siguientes parámetros:

> ```
> miprograma.out JAISON 34 37 2
> ```

Donde Jaison es el nombre, 37 es la edad 2 es el dinero, por lo el `printf`, debería devolver: `"Mi nombre es Jaison, mi edad es 42 y tengo 5  en la cartera"`.

Pero no es así debido a que, `argv[1]`, `argv[2]` y `argv[3]` no se corresponde con los tipos... y no se como asignar a las variables nombre, edad y dinero los argumentos.

Comment: Lo que quiero es poder trabajar con el entero que me han pasado como parametro en mi programa, sumandole por ejemplo otro valor o asignarlo a otra variable. Muchas gracias por tu respuesta

Comment: El único problema que tienes que resolver es la conversión de cadena a otros tipos, ya que las variables `argv[1]`, etc son de tipo `char*`, es decir, cadenas de caracteres, mientras que los tipos con los que pretendes trabajar serían entero, flotante, etc. No es tanto un problema de acceso a los argumentos como de conversión de cadena a otra cosa. Investiga `atoi()`, `atof()`, ...

Answer (score 0):

Este sería tu código minimamente reproducible:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int edad;
    char nombre[30];
    float dinero;

    strcpy(nombre, argv[1]);
    edad = atoi(argv[2]);
    dinero = atof(argv[3]);

    edad = edad + 5;
    dinero = dinero + 3;

    printf("Mi nombre es %s, mi edad es %d y tengo %f dinero en la cartera", nombre, edad, dinero);
}
```

Tu solución como bien apuntaba abulafia es que C es muy estricto con sus tipos de variable y para solventar eso existen funciones auxiliares para la conversión.

En este caso seria `atoi()` y `atof()` que convierten "AsciiToInteger" y "AsciiToFloat" (caracteres ascii a enteros y ascii a flotante) que se encuentran en la libreria estandard de C `stdlib.h`.

El siguiente problema que te surgirá es "qué ocurre cuando el usuario introduzca un argumento en una posición equivocada o un valor erróneo", como por ejemplo poner treinta en lugar de 30 para la edad.

Un saludo

Answer (score 0):

La función main en C o C++ como bien indican puede devolver dos parámetros (usualmente), `argc` y `argv`.
El primero correcponde al número de parámetros que se le pasa por la línea de comandos, el segundo es un array de chars que guarda estos parámetros para poder imprimirlos.
Lo que te queda, es trasformar esos tipos a tus tipos específicos (int, char [ ] y float) bien haciendo castings o utilizando funciones específicas de C.

por ejemplo:

```
int edad = (int)argv[2];
```

Nota, que estoy poniendo la segunda posición ya que la 0, está reservada al nombre del programa, por tanto tu primer argumento será el de la posición 1 del array.

Un saludo

Comment: El segundo parámetro no es un *array de chars*, sino, un *puntero doble*. Hacer un conversión de este tipo: `int edad = (int)argv[2];` es ilegal en C, estás guardando una dirección de memoria en una variable entera. Si o si, hay que usar funciones como [atoi](https://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/atoi/) para convertir de `string` a `int`, ya que `argv[2]` devuelve la dirección base de una cadena.

Answer (score 0):

Para hacer el código más robusto puedes usar las funciones `strtol` y `strtof`  para detectar errores en los valores numéricos.

Lo primero, en un caso como este en el que se espera un determinado número de parámetros, es comprobar que los hemos recibido todos utilizando `argc`.

Para cadenas de tamaño fijo es siempre recomendable limitar la cantidad de datos a copiar utilizando `strncpy` o versiones más seguras con el fin de evitar desbordamientos de pila.

En el ejemplo he abortado la ejecución del programa en el caso de que haya algún error de conversión en los datos, sin embargo, nótese que `strtol` y `strtof` convierten el número hasta donde pueden, devolviendo en `endptr` el caracter de la cadena original en la que pararon la conversión.

El código quedaría de la siguiente forma:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main (int argc, char *argv[]) {
  int   edad;
  char  nombre[30], *endptr;
  float dinero;

  if (argc != 4) {
    fprintf (stderr, "Número inválido de parámetros\n");
    exit (1);
  }
  strncpy (nombre, argv[1], 30);
  edad = strtol (argv[2], &endptr, 10);
  if (*endptr) {
    fprintf (stderr, "Segundo parámetro invalido\n");
    exit (1);
  }
  dinero = strtof (argv[3], &endptr);
  if (*endptr) {
    fprintf (stderr, "Tercer parámetro invalido\n");
    exit (1);
  }

  printf("Mi nombre es %s, mi edad es %d y tengo %.2f dinero en la cartera\n",
     nombre, edad, dinero);
  return 0;
}
```